# Field 'id' expected a number but got <customerlogin: customerlogin object (4)>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to add customer and salon to their respective tables according to what option is selected by the user.I gave "Customer" and 'Salon owner" in dropdown menu.The name given in dropdown menu is "category". If a user select "Customer" from dropdown menu, registration form details should be added to customerlogin and customerreg tables.Similarly, in the case of "Salon owner".But unfortunately when any of these two option is selected,details were added to both customerlogin table and salonlogin table but not to other two tables.

**Views.py**

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    ufname = request.POST.get('fname')
    ulname = request.POST.get('lname')
    uemail = request.POST.get('email')
    upassword = request.POST.get('password')
    umobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
    ucategory = request.POST.get('category')
    uaddress = request.POST.get('address')

    if (salonreg.objects.filter(Email=uemail).exists() or customerreg.objects.filter(Email=uemail).exists()):
        messages.info(request, "Email ID Already Taken")
        return redirect('register')
    elif (salonreg.objects.filter(Mobile=umobile).exists() or customerreg.objects.filter(Mobile=umobile).exists()):
        messages.info(request, "Mobile Number Already Taken")
        return redirect('register')

    elif (ucategory=="Customer"):
        cloginobj = customerlogin()
        cloginobj.Username = uemail
        cloginobj.Password = upassword
        cloginobj.save()

        cuserreg = customerreg()
        cuserreg.Login_id_id = cloginobj
        cuserreg.First_name = ufname
        cuserreg.Last_name = ulname
        cuserreg.Email = uemail
        cuserreg.Password = upassword
        cuserreg.Mobile = umobile
        cuserreg.Address = uaddress
        cuserreg.save()
        cuserdetail = customerreg.objects.get(Email=uemail)
        request.session["userid"] = cuserdetail.id
        return render(request, "profile.html", {'userdetail': userdetail})


    else:
        sloginobj = salonlogin()
        sloginobj.Username = uemail
        sloginobj.Password = upassword
        sloginobj.save()

        ssalonreg = salonreg()
        ssalonreg.Login_id = sloginobj.id
        ssalonreg.First_name = ufname
        ssalonreg.Last_name = ulname
        ssalonreg.Email = uemail
        ssalonreg.Password = upassword
        ssalonreg.Mobile = umobile
        ssalonreg.Address = uaddress
        ssalonreg.save()
        ssalondetail = salonreg.objects.get(Email=uemail)
        request.session["salonid"] = ssalondetail.id
        return render(request, "salon_owner.html", {'userdetail': userdetail})

else:
    return render(request, "register.html")
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class salonlogin(models.Model):
    Username=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    Password=models.CharField(max_length=20)


class salonreg(models.Model):
    Login_id=models.ForeignKey(salonlogin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    First_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Email=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    Password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Mobile= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Address=models.CharField(max_length=250)

class customerlogin(models.Model):
    Username=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    Password=models.CharField(max_length=20)


class customerreg(models.Model):
    Login_id=models.ForeignKey(salonlogin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    First_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Email=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    Password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Mobile= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Address=models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Can anyone suggest a best way to solve this issue.

Comment: The is no difference in your models why even have different models? Just add a field to indicate which type of user it is. Also why are you not using [the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system)?

Answer (score 1):

Correct these two lines in views

```
ssalonreg.Login_id = sloginobj
cuserreg.Login_id = cloginobj
```

also correct the mistake in models.py

```
class customerreg(models.Model):
    Login_id=models.ForeignKey(salonlogin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to

```
class customerreg(models.Model):
    Login_id=models.ForeignKey(customerlogin,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: After correcting above two lines,"salon" tables works properly but "customerreg" table not@tifat hasan

Comment: its because of the wrong model refence in `customerreg` table